# Kentico files version does not match database version. Is it still safe to apply hotfix?

Tags: kentico-11

The files of the kentico site in every way say that it is version 11.0.10.

The database, however, says it is version 11.0.6.

Attempting to install the latest hotfix (11.0.49)

The site was site up by a third party so I'm not sure what process they may have used that got things out of sync. Are the database changes small enough or the hotfix cumulative enough that I can ignore the minor version differences?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the easiest fix is to install the SQL script from the 11.0.10 hotfix to get the database up to date and then install the latest hotfix.